# Creating a nested model for "new" action in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible #.....

  belongs_to :owner
end
```

And there is a controller's action:

```
  def new
    @data1 = MyModel.new
  end
```

And a view:

```
= f.select :owner_id, options_from_collection_for_select(MyModel.some_scope, :id, :full_name, @data1.owner.id)
```

Obviously, `@data1.owner.id` is empty. How do I make it "non-empty"?

Comment: Misspelling? `owner.id` should be `owner_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `@data1.owner.id` is empty is because `@data1` doesn't have an owner.

You can generate an owner by adding this line to the new action in your controller:

```
@data1.create_owner
```

Where the arguments you pass into this method are the attributes of your owner. For example, they might have a first_name of Marius:

```
@data1.create_owner(first_name: 'Marius')
```

Seeing that you're doing this in the new method, unless you've got some not-null constraints on any of the attributes for an owner, I presume you might want to just leave it blank though.

Creating this owner for `@data1` should populate it with an id, making `@data1.owner.id` "non-empty".

Answer (score -1):

If you "know" the owner at the moment of creation new MyModel you can do (assuming `own` is a ref to object of Owner):

```
@data1 = own.mymodels.new()
```

So `@data1` should be a ref to new MyModel object with `owner_id` set to own's `id`.